# Creating a local proxy to chain other proxies through

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy

I would like to use Python to do the following:
Create a local proxy which I can use with my script. Chain another proxy to the local one, so I'm actually connecting through that one. Then be able to change which proxy the local one is connecting through on the fly, so that the script will always connect to the same local proxy, but will really use a different outgoing proxy each time.

Now, excuse me if I'm using some of the wrong terms here, I don't quite know what it's called, but I hope you get the idea, from my poor explanation.

I'm hoping that this will be relatively simple or that there's a python module that can help me accomplish this, but if not, please help me with some terms, so I can seek further knowledge about this.

Thank you.

Edit: For further explanation of my problem, please see my comment below.

Comment: I had trouble understanding this. What do you want to achieve? Perhaps try to explain it without using the word 'proxy'.

Comment: Alright, I'll explain it a bit better. I have a Python script using the selenium webdriver module. It allows you to automate actions on a website, like filling in forms and so on. I can set it up so the browser it uses will use a proxy to access the web. Unfortunately, I can't change the proxy settings while the browser is running, forcing me to restart the browser every time I want to change proxy. This takes a lot of time, so I would rather avoid it. (continues in next comment)

Comment: Therefore I was thinking, if you could create some kind of local proxy, with python, which would then direct the connection onto another proxy, handled by the script. That way, I would be able to change which proxy was being used to connect to the website, without changing the actual proxy settings of the webdriver.